# JSR310Module could not be instantiated

Tags: jackson

I have a simple program to deserialize a JSON object to Java Class, I'm using a Jackson library. I'm getting the below error ? Please advide. Thanks.

Sample application can be found at https://github.com/Manjesh80/question

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module
```

The program is

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.time.OffsetDateTime;


    public class JacksonGenericDataBinding {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            JacksonGenericDataBinding jacksonGenericDataBinding = new JacksonGenericDataBinding();
            jacksonGenericDataBinding.deserializeEvent();
        }

        public void deserializeEvent() throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();


            Event event = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/event.json"), Event.class);
            System.out.println("Event ID ==>" + event.getDeviceID());
        }
    }
```

event.json

{
    "deviceID": "Ethernet",
    "networkID": "Net-01",
    "eventTime": "2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00"
  }

Comment: Check out the class-level comment in com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module - you're using a obsolete / deprecated version.   (Now, java.util.ServiceLoader modules must have a noargs constructor...)

Comment: (update to at least >= 2.5 in your pom.xml)

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I did not realize the version.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue when I was using Jasper 6.1.0 and Azure Blob Storage together. The both were adding two version of Jackson dependencies.
e.g.

1. Jasper was adding Jackson 2.1
2. Azure Blob was adding Jackson 2.8

To resolve this issue, just excluded the older version from Jasper and now it is working fine